# Column with math mode in beamer won't center under multicolumn row

Tags: tables, beamer, math-mode, multicolumn

I am having trouble getting a table to behave as I expect (and want) and I don't know if the problem is with beamer, multicolumn, or math mode.

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$y=x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y=x^2$}\\\midrule
$x$ & $y$ & $x$ & $y$ \\ \midrule
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The second row, `$x$ & $y$ & $x$ & $y$`, is not centered but left justified. If I put a row of text between the multicolumn row and the one containing math-mode the centering works, but not as is and I have no idea why or how to fix it without adding a row I don't want/need. I have built with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX with updated packages and on WriteLaTeX all with the same result.

Comment: When I compile your MWE, my "x y x y" row is center-aligned with the numbers below it, although the row is left=justified with the `\midrule`s and `\bottomrule`.  Is it this latter point that is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please compare:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
%\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\begin{tabular}{cccc@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$y=x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y=x^2$}\\\midrule
$x$ & $y$ & $x$ & $y$ \\ \midrule
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$y=x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y=x^2$}\\\midrule
$x$ & $y$ & $x$ & $y$ \\ \midrule
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Hence it is enough to remove the first `@{}`.

[image]

Comment: That does indeed work, thank you. Perhaps I don't understand just what the @{} is doing; I thought it was simply removing excess width from the \midrule and \bottomrule, but this appears to be different behavior.